# Async file write issue

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await

I have the next test method where I am testing the [async file write](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/01/23/using-async-for-file-access-alan-berman.aspx):

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    List<Task> tasks = null;
    int x = 1;
    int step = 10;
    for (int i = step; i <=200; i = i + step)
    {
        tasks = Enumerable.Range(x, step).Select(async y =>
            {
                await TextFile.WriteTextAsync("file.txt", String.Format("{0}\n", y));
            }).ToList();

        x = i + 1;
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Async file write code:

```
public static async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
{
    byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite,
        bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
    };
}
```

The problem is that my code producing the file that not contained all expected values.

I am expecting to see the values from 1 to 200 in the file but instead I have e.g

```
1 
3
5
7
8

12
13
14 
...
```

See detailed file here http://bit.ly/1JVMAyg
May be some one have an idea what is going on and how to fix that?

**NOTE:** Please see my solution below that is fixing the problem with missing items not being inserted in to file but it is breaking the whole idea of multithreading mentioned @LasseV.Karlsen in his comment. I am happy to see if some one have better solution that wont break multithreading .

Comment: You've got multiple threads writing to the same file at the same time. That seems unlikely to end well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @JonSkeet. I've got it. I had to limit the access to the 'WriteTextAsync' method and here is my solution:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim _thread= new SemaphoreSlim(1);    
public static async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
{
    byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
    await _sync.WaitAsync();
    try
    {

        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
            FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite,
            bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
        {
            await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
        };
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        _thread.Release();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: 
This solution is fixing the problem with missed items didnt inserted to the file but now it is limiting the `WriteTextAsync` with just only single thread accessing the file in a point of time as @LasseV.Karlsen mentioned.

So looks like my solution is fixing the problem but breaking the whole idea of multithreading and I am happy to see if some one have better solution that wont break multithreading .

Comment: But if you end up with only one thread at a time writing to the file, why the whole thread thing then? You're basically sending N shoppers into the store but the store only have one line for checkout, or am I missing something?

Comment: @LasseVKarlsen Actually I see no threading at all...unless the default scheduler is umm.. The default scheduler...